# Get the length of each line in file with C and write in output file

Tags: c

I am a biology student and I am trying to learn perl, python and C and also use the scripts in my work. So, I have a file as follows:

```
>sequence1
ATCGATCGATCG
>sequence2
AAAATTTT
>sequence3
CCCCGGGG
```

The output should look like this, that is the name of each sequence and the count of characters in each line and printing the total number of sequences in the end of the file.

```
sequence1 12
sequence2 8
sequence3 8
Total number of sequences = 3
```

I could make the perl and python scripts work, this is the python script as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

my_file = open(sys.argv[1]) #open the file
my_output = open(sys.argv[2], "w") #open output file

total_sequence_counts = 0

for line in my_file: 
    if line.startswith(">"):
        sequence_name = line.rstrip('\n').replace(">","") 
        total_sequence_counts += 1 
        continue    
    dna_length = len(line.rstrip('\n')) 
    my_output.write(sequence_name + " " + str(dna_length) + '\n')
my_output.write("Total number of sequences = " + str(total_sequence_counts) + '\n')
```

Now, I want to write the same script in C, this is what I have achieved so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
input = FILE *fopen(const char *filename, "r");
output = FILE *fopen(const char *filename, "w"); 

double total_sequence_counts = 0;
char sequence_name[];

char line [4095]; // set a temporary line length
char buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(line) +1); // allocate some memory

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), filename) != NULL) { // read until new line character is not found in line

    buffer = realloc(*buffer, strlen(line) + strlen(buffer) + 1); // realloc buffer to adjust buffer size
    if (buffer == NULL) { // print error message if memory allocation fails
        printf("\n Memory error");
        return 0;
    }
    if (line[0] == ">") {
        sequence_name = strcpy(sequence_name, &line[1]); 
        total_sequence_counts += 1
        }
        else {
            double length = strlen(line);
            fprintf(output, "%s \t %ld", sequence_name, length);
        }
    fprintf(output, "%s \t %ld", "Total number of sequences = ", total_sequence_counts);
}
    int fclose(FILE *input); // when you are done working with a file, you should close it using this function. 
    return 0;
    int fclose(FILE *output);
    return 0;
}
```

But this code, of course is full of mistakes, my problem is that despite studying a lot, I still can't properly understand and use the memory allocation and pointers so I know I especially have mistakes in that part. It would be great if you could comment on my code and see how it can turn into a script that actually work. By the way, in my actual data, the length of each line is not defined so I need to use malloc and realloc for that purpose.

Comment: You need to set a size for the `sequence_name` array, or it will have no size and all writing to it will be out of bounds leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: And before attempting a more complex piece of code like this, learn the basic first. Start with more basic code to learn how to handle arrays, pointers and dynamic memory allocation. Well, looking at how you handle the file opening/closing, you should probably start with a tutorial on file handling first. You must learn to crawl before you can stand up and walk.

Comment: You should compile with maximum warnings enabled. Then think about all warnings and try to eliminate them.

Comment: For some functions you seem to have copy-pasted the entire prototype in, e.g. `int fclose(FILE *input);`, that's not a function call. It should be just `fclose(input);`. The calls to `fopen()` are strange too, should use `argv[]` for their filenames.

Comment: `double length = strlen(line);`, is that because you expect some of your lines to have 0.5 characters or because they could exceed `MAX_INT`?

Comment: Certainly `char *buffer = malloc (sizeof(line) +1);`  (Add * before buffer).  And `realloc(buffer. ...` (no *)  Suggest compiling code with all warnings enabled - many minor problems that take way from an otherwise thoughtful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple program like this, where you look at short lines one at a time, you shouldn't worry about dynamic memory allocation. It is probably good enough to use local buffers of a reasonable size.

Another thing is that C isn't particularly suited for quick-and-dirty string processing. For example, there isn't a `strstrip` function in the standard library. You usually end up implementing such behaviour yourself.

An example implementation looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>



#define MAXLEN 80       /* Maximum line length, including null terminator */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;

    char line[MAXLEN];          /* Current line buffer */
    char ref[MAXLEN] = "";      /* Sequence reference buffer */
    int nseq = 0;               /* Sequence counter */

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile outfile\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);        
    }

    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s for writing.\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);        
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in)) {
        int len = strlen(line);

        /* Strip whitespace from end */
        while (len > 0 && isspace(line[len - 1])) len--;
        line[len] = '\0';

        if (line[0] == '>') {
            /* First char is '>': copy from second char in line */
            strcpy(ref, line + 1);
        } else {
            /* Other lines are sequences */
            fprintf(out, "%s: %d\n", ref, len);
            nseq++;
        }
    }

    fprintf(out, "Total number of sequences. %d\n", nseq);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

A lot of code is about enforcing arguments and opening and closing files. (You could cut out a lot of code if you used `stdin` and `stdout` with file redirections.)

The core is the big `while` loop. Things to note:

- `fgets` returns `NULL` on error or when the end of file is reached.
- The first lines determine the length of the line and then remove white-space from the end.
- It is not enough to decrement length, at the end the stripped string must be terminated with the null character `'\0'`
- When you check the first character in the line, you should check against a char, not a string. In C, single and double quotes are not interchangeable. `">"` is a string literal of two characters, `'>'` and the terminating `'\0'`.
- When dealing with countable entities like chars in a string, use integer types, not floating-point numbers. (I've used (signed) `int` here, but because there can't be a negative number of chars in a line, it might have been better to have used an unsigned type.)
- The notation `line + 1` is equivalent to `&line[1]`.
- The code I've shown doesn't check that there is always one reference per sequence. I'll leave this as exercide to the reader.

For a beginner, this can be quite a lot to keep track of. For small text-processing tasks like yours, Python and Perl are definitely better suited.

**Edit**: The solution above won't work for long sequences; it is restricted to `MAXLEN` characters. But you don't need dynamic allocation if you only need the length, not the contents of the sequences.

Here's an updated version that doesn't read lines, but read characters instead. In `'>'` context, it stored the reference. Otherwise it just keeps a count:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>      /* for isspace() */



#define MAXLEN 80       /* Maximum line length, including null terminator */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;

    int nseq = 0;               /* Sequence counter */
    char ref[MAXLEN];           /* Reference name */

    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    /* Snip: Argument and file checking as above */

    while (1) {
        int c = getc(in);

        if (c == EOF) break;

        if (c == '>') {
            int n = 0;

            c = fgetc(in);
            while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
                if (n < sizeof(ref) - 1) ref[n++] = c;
                c = fgetc(in);
            }
            ref[n] = '\0';
        } else {
            int len = 0;
            int n = 0;

            while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
                n++;
                if (!isspace(c)) len = n;
                c = fgetc(in);
            }

            fprintf(out, "%s: %d\n", ref, len);
            nseq++;
        }
    }

    fprintf(out, "Total number of sequences. %d\n", nseq);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `fgetc` reads a single byte from a file and returns this byte or `EOF` when the file has ended. In this implementation, that's the only reading function used.
- Storing a reference string is implemented via `fgetc` here too. You could probably use `fgets` after skipping the initial angle bracket, too.
- The counting just reads bytes without storing them. `n` is the total count, `len` is the count up to the last non-space. (Your lines probably consist only of ACGT without any trailing space, so you could skip the test for space and use `n` instead of `len`.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Indeed, I am using python and perl to process my files but I really want to learn C, maybe more out of curiosity than need, and I thought it is good to try to write the same code in three languages, but I need to practice more to understand C better.

Comment: In my real files, the lengths of the lines can go up to several thousands characters or even a million. That was the reason I was trying to use memory allocations, more importantly, I was hoping for more explanations on that to go one step forward in understanding them.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, even if it didn't solve your problem. I've updated my answer to include a solution that only counts the chars without storing them, which you might find useful. When you need to store the lines, you need to worry about memory allocation, of course. If you are on Linux, `getline` reads lines from a file and cares about the allocation. That might be easier than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *my_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *my_output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    int total_sequence_coutns = 0;
    char *sequence_name;
    int dna_length;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    while(-1 != getline(&line, &size, my_file)){
        if(line[0] == '>'){
            sequence_name = strdup(strtok(line, ">\n"));
            total_sequence_coutns +=1;
            continue;
        }
        dna_length = strlen(strtok(line, "\n"));
        fprintf(my_output, "%s %d\n", sequence_name, dna_length);
        free(sequence_name);
    }
    fprintf(my_output, "Total number of sequences = %d\n", total_sequence_coutns);
    fclose(my_file);
    fclose(my_output);
    free(line);
    return (0);
}
```